# Daisy chaining IOT devices without switches?

Tags: ip, ipv4, nat, ip-address, linux

I have multiple IoT board with two network interface in each device. I want to connect them in a daisy chain without help of switch. The eth1 of first device will be connected to eth0 of second device, eth1 of second device will be connected to eth0 of third device..and so on.

Now with such a connection, is it possible to have same static IP address for all IoT device? eth0 as 10.0.0.1 and eth1 as 10.0.0.2.

```
+--------------------------+      +--------------------------+           +-------------------------+
|                          |      |                          |           |                         |
|  10.0.0.1      10.0.0.2  +------> 10.0.0.1      10.0.0.2   +---...-----> 10.0.0.1                |
|                          |      |                          |           |                         |
|                          |      |                          |           |                         |
|                          |      |                          |           |                         |
|                          |      |                          |           |                         |
|          Sys-1           |      |          Sys-2           |           |          Sys-'n'        |
+--------------------------+      +--------------------------+           +-------------------------+
```

How should network be configured for this?

Is this IP address duplication?

(ping 10.0.0.1 should be routed to eth1 instead of eth0)

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Network Engineering!  Yes, you are duplicating addresses, so your idea will not work. Each link between devices is a separate network and needs its own IP subnet with unique addresses.